# Incorrect date conversion of JSON dates using moment, OffSet value is ignored

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am making an api call and getting the below response.

```
{
    "Country": "U.S.A.",
    "FaceValueCcy": "",
    "IsApproved": true,
    "MDate": "/Date(1742130000000+1100)/",
    "MtmInUsd": 0,
}
```

When I am trying to convert the MDate into 'DD-MMM-YYYY' format. I am expecting the result as '17-Mar-2025' but it is giving me the output as '16-Mar-2025'. This is the code I am using to convert the date.

```
moment('/Date(1742130000000+1100)/').utc().format('DD-MMM-YYYY')
```

When I query the value '1742130000000' in [epochconvertor](https://www.epochconverter.com/), it gives me 16-Mar-2025. why moment is ignoring +1100? Is there any alternate way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```js
moment.parseZone('/Date(1742130000000+1100)/').format('DD-MMM-YYYY')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `parseZone()` to keep the offset.

```js
console.log(moment.parseZone('/Date(1742130000000+1100)/').utc().format('DD-MMM-YYYY'));

console.log(moment.parseZone('/Date(1742130000000+1100)/').utc().format()); // full time
console.log(moment.parseZone('/Date(1742130000000+1100)/').format()); // full time without UTC conversion
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Reference: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3291

Answer (score 1):

Use paeseZone

```
moment('/Date(1742130000000+1100)/').parseZone().format('DD-MMM-YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution.

1. Maybe the issue in "/" try to remove that.
2. Try `moment.unix(timestamp).formate("DD-MMM-YYYY")`